# Which book is good to start with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Which books are good to start with LINQ. It would be helpful if the book can cover from basics to Intermediate level.

Comment: in addition to getting a book, check out LinqPad. lets you mess around with linq w/o having to build an entire program. it's neet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how long a book recommendation question will hang around here, answers may be merged with an existing community wiki question on recommended .NET books (I'm sure there is one) - however, what I might suggest, though lacking in descriptive content and focusing directly on practice, is:

- [101 Linq Samples over on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Further:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492934/good-book-to-quickly-learn-linq#4493513) to another question recommends [Essential Linq](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321564162)
- [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275726/advanced-linq-book#1275750) adds recommendations for [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), [Linq In Action](http://www.manning.com/marguerie/)
- Yet another suggestion [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887204/advanced-level-vb-net-book-recommendation-with-good-lambda-expressions-and-linq-c#889238) is [Pro Linq](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597893)
- Lastly, and credit to @Laurent, is [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx)

Comment: The Jon Skeet's "Reimplementing LINQ" post suite give a very good overview about what the philosophy of LINQ is if you talk rather c# than another natural language ;) https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/code.aspx) which has several chapters covering LINQ and PLINQ. Additionally it is a really useful reference on several other topics such as threading and TPL as well.

Following that I would recommend [Jon Skeet's series on how to implement LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/03/18/edulinq-the-e-book.aspx) as it gives a great insight into why LINQ is constructed the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I got a lot of useful info Pro Linq from Joseph rattz

I have the C#2008 version, seems there is a newer version for 2010 on the market as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say Jon Skeet's C# In Depth. LINQ actually builds on several techniques - anonymous delegates, extension methods, iterators - so getting a feel for all of them is important. I recommend the Skeet book wholeheartedly. And he has about a billion points on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

My development team (include myself) have all learned using [Programming Microsoft LINQ](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Microsoft-PRO-Developer-Paolo-Pialorsi/dp/0735624003/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1305557729&sr=8-1)  by Microsoft Press.

What I found particuarly useful is that it does not jump too quickly into the LINQ-to-SQL topics and so by the time you arrive at that particular topic you have a full appreciation of what the technology can do rather than just seeing it as a data entity framework.