# C# Library Management console program

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, csharpcodeprovider, icsharpcode

In this code when I add 2 books and try to delete 1st and 2nd book, 1st gets deleted and 2nd one didn't. In next case when I add 3 books and delete one by one 1 gets deleted and 2 not and 3rd one becomes missing when I delete 2. When I add 4 books 2 and 4 not deleted.

My code (I'm a trainee so I'm a beginner in C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LibraryManagement
{
    //Defining a class Book
    class Book
    {
        public int bookId;
        public string bookName;
        public int bookPrice;
        public int bookCount;
        public int x;
    }
    //Defining a class Borrow
    class BorrowDetails
    {
        public int userId;
        public string userName;
        public string userAddress;
        public int borrowBookId;
        public DateTime borrowDate;
        public int borrowCount;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        static List<BorrowDetails> borrowList = new List<BorrowDetails>();
        static Book book = new Book();
        static BorrowDetails borrow = new BorrowDetails();

        //Password verfication and Menu 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Welcome !!!\nEnter your password :");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (password == "sync")
            {
                bool close = true;
                while (close)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nMenu\n" +
                    "1)Add book\n" +
                    "2)Delete book\n" +
                    "3)Search book\n" +
                    "4)Borrow book\n" +
                    "5)Return book\n" +
                    "6)Close\n\n");
                    Console.Write("Choose your option from menu :");

                    int option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (option == 1)
                    {
                        GetBook();
                    }
                    else if (option == 2)
                    {
                        RemoveBook();
                    }
                    else if (option == 3)
                    {
                        SearchBook();
                    }
                    else if (option == 4)
                    {
                        Borrow();
                    }
                    else if (option == 5)
                    {
                        ReturnBook();
                    }
                    else if (option == 6)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you");
                        close = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option\nRetry !!!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid password");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //To add book details to the Library database
        public static void GetBook()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            Console.WriteLine("Book Id:{0}", book.bookId = bookList.Count + 1);
            Console.Write("Book Name:");
            book.bookName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Book Price:");
            book.bookPrice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Number of Books:");
            book.x = book.bookCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bookList.Add(book);
        }

        //To delete book details from the Library database 
        public static void RemoveBook()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            Console.Write("Enter Book id to be deleted : ");

            int Del = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (bookList.Exists(x => x.bookId == Del))
            {
                bookList.RemoveAt(Del - 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Book id - {0} has been deleted", Del);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Book id");
            }

            bookList.Add(book);
        }

        //To search book details from the Library database using Book id 
        public static void SearchBook()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            Console.Write("Search by BOOK id :");
            int find = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (bookList.Exists(x => x.bookId == find))
            {
                foreach (Book searchId in bookList)
                {
                    if (searchId.bookId == find)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Book id :{0}\n" +
                        "Book name :{1}\n" +
                        "Book price :{2}\n" +
                        "Book Count :{3}", searchId.bookId, searchId.bookName, searchId.bookPrice, searchId.bookCount);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book id {0} not found", find);
            }
        }

        //To borrow book details from the Library
        public static void Borrow()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            BorrowDetails borrow = new BorrowDetails();
            Console.WriteLine("User id : {0}", (borrow.userId = borrowList.Count + 1));
            Console.Write("Name :");

            borrow.userName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Book id :");
            borrow.borrowBookId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Number of Books : ");
            borrow.borrowCount= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Address :");
            borrow.userAddress = Console.ReadLine();
            borrow.borrowDate = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Date - {0} and Time - {1}", borrow.borrowDate.ToShortDateString(), borrow.borrowDate.ToShortTimeString());

            if (bookList.Exists(x => x.bookId == borrow.borrowBookId))
            {
                foreach (Book searchId in bookList)
                {
                    if (searchId.bookCount >= searchId.bookCount - borrow.borrowCount && searchId.bookCount - borrow.borrowCount >= 0)
                    {
                        if (searchId.bookId == borrow.borrowBookId)
                        {
                            searchId.bookCount = searchId.bookCount - borrow.borrowCount;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Only {0} books are found", searchId.bookCount);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book id {0} not found", borrow.borrowBookId);
            }
            borrowList.Add(borrow);
        }

        //To return borrowed book to the library 
        public static void ReturnBook()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter following details :");

            Console.Write("Book id : ");
            int returnId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Number of Books:");
            int returnCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (bookList.Exists(y => y.bookId == returnId))
            {
                foreach (Book addReturnBookCount in bookList)
                {
                    if (addReturnBookCount.x >= returnCount + addReturnBookCount.bookCount)
                    {
                        if (addReturnBookCount.bookId == returnId)
                        {
                            addReturnBookCount.bookCount = addReturnBookCount.bookCount + returnCount;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Count exists the actual count");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book id {0} not found", returnId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove a book, your booklist is being reordered so the book ids no longer reflect the position that they were in when you added them.
E.g. your bookList has 2 books (bookList[0] and bookList[1]). When you delete 1 book, you are left with booklist[0], so when you try and delete the next book (with your code it says you using del -1 to get the position) you are then trying to delete from your array at bookList[1] which of course, does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `books` by using the `bookId` or more specifically by the unique Id of the object. Your posted code is removing it from the list using the position of book. The sole purpose of having a `bookId` is to identify the book from any number of `books` and then quickly manipulate it using code.

Let me tell you something about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) which will help you some way. Every object has three features in it:

1. Identity
2. State
3. Behavior

Here, Identity (something unique like a `bookId` which can be used to select it) is the thing that you should use to manipulate your objects (books), not the position of the object.

Enough theory, In your code

```
bookList.RemoveAt(Del - 1);
```

is the culprit. Change it to work on the basis of `bookId` and your problem will be solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are mixing up the `List` and `Array` data structure. Let's take a closer look:

```
if (bookList.Exists(x => x.bookId == Del))
```

Here you are using the iterative search in your book list for a book. First of all, you can do it faster by introducing additional dictionary, then your program will be faster. Second is that after this, you get the `id` of the book, and remove previous book, as it is not a list, but the array:

```
bookList.RemoveAt(Del - 1);
```

Why this isn't work as expected? It's simple, lets say that you've added three books, and your list looks like (arrows here are links between books in your list):

```
1 --> 2 --> 3
```

After deleting the second book your list looks like:

```
1 --> 3
```

If you add another book, it will have id equal to `3`! because of this line (`bookList.Count` equal to 2 here):

```
Console.WriteLine("Book Id:{0}", book.bookId = bookList.Count + 1);
```

So your list looks like this:

```
1 --> 3 --> 3
```

So you have to maintain additional counter for unique identification for your books. Another thing is that you have to learn is additional LINQ methods which you can use, such as [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) for easy delete from list, `Find` for easy searching into the list, and so on. You can find some advises about LINQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018401/213550).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is inconstancy in book id. It should be unique in list to identify correct book.

Here is quick fix .

Add Linq namespace in project :

```
using System.Linq;
```

Modify GetBook() Method to generate unique bookId by using max book id number from list

```
var bookId = bookList.Count> 0 ? bookList.Max(b => b.bookId) : 0;
Console.WriteLine("Book Id:{0}", book.bookId = bookId + 1);
```